# WebKit CSS: Use for -webkit-border-image a picture from an image array

Tags: css, webkit

in my webapp for iPhone/Android/BB6 I try to put all the images into image array (something like here http://goo.gl/VcMcj), in order to optimize loading times.

In most cases it works fine with background-position/width/height-properties.
Now I would like to put my -webkit-border-image's into image array, but can't figure out how.

It that possible?

Thnaks in advance!

Comment: Does something not work specifically on the mobile browsers? Does it work in desktop Safari? Could you make a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) example?

Comment: What I have now is -  for each border picture I have an entry in CSS like this: someElement{ -webkit-border-image: url("../images/somepicture.png") 0 5 0 13;}. What I actually whant is, that all the images are stored not in different files, but in one file - image array.

Comment: Everything's working fine, except that, I have no idea how to put the border-images into single image array and whether it's possible.

Comment: It does seem to be kinda possible, depending on how you're using `-webkit-border-image` (at least in my quick test in Google Chrome). Please make an example on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) which closely represents your use case.

Comment: Thanks for taking time. Here's the jsf - http://jsfiddle.net/LZAp3/ .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I combined and tweaked the first two buttons into one image:

[image]

[***Live Demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/LZAp3/1/)

```
#leftnav a:first-child {
    /* 0 5 0 13 */
    -webkit-border-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iz5Jl.png) 0 5 30 13
}

#leftbutton a,#rightbutton a,#imbutton a {
    /* 0 5 0 5 */
    -webkit-border-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iz5Jl.png) 30 5 0 5
}
```

Possibly not worth the hassle for the minuscule file sizes and number of images involved here.

---

While I was looking at this, I found a site which made testing *so much easier*:

http://border-image.com

---

I couldn't get the textbox border working with, so I left that one alone:

This is the image I made and was trying with before I gave up, if it helps:

[image]